# PropertyGrid RTL support

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid, right-to-left

Is it possible to switch `PropertyGrid` to RTL layout? Seems to be that setting `RightToLeft` property to `Yes` does not do the job. There are `RtlTranslateAlignments` and `RtlTranslateContent` methods in `PropertyGrid`, should I use it in any way?

If this property is unsupported are there free analogues that support RTL layout correctly?

Note: I'm using `PropertyGrid` in C++/CLI.

Comment: Do you find solution for your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear there is no free solution that will let you display the grid as RTL. From my own experience I can tell you that it takes a component developed from scratch to be able to draw the grid "reversed" and have inplace controls that behave the same.

Comment: Any paid solutions?

Comment: @CSharper [Smart PropertyGrid.Net](http://visualhint.com/propertygrid) has support for RTL. Note: I'm the author of this component.